# "Parameter X Value Y is out of range" being returned by INDEX combined with RANDBETWEEN

Tags: google-sheets

I'm making a random team selector but I'm getting a `#NUM!` error saying that "Parameter 2 Value 20" or "Parameter 2 Value 25" is out of range. From what I understand, they are not.

The parameters referred by the function are in other sheets.[. Here is the link to it.](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1B-V1WDS9je_6j6St2FTFt6VNufSHHXJYLuVZejtxcRU/edit?usp=sharing) Example:

[image: Various football club emblems]

Do you think this is a bug or am I doing something wrong?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I see commands like

```
=index(Spain!A$2:A$19, randbetween(2,19))
```

The second parameter of `index` is not the absolute row number but is relative to the range specified as the first argument. For example,

- `=index(A$2:A$19, 1)` refers to A2
- `=index(A$2:A$19, 18)` refers to A19
- `=index(A$2:A$19, 19)` throws an error

To fix this, either change the range of `randbetween`:

```
=index(Spain!A$2:A$19, randbetween(1,18))
```

or, if you want to refer by absolute row numbers, use [`indirect`](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093377):

```
=indirect("Spain!A"&randbetween(2,19))
```

Comment: That's a nice and elegant solution. Thank you very much. I still didn't quite get why index combined with randbetween didn't work, I do understand that the function didn't quite work for what I intended though. Any chance of you giving another explanation for me? (I might research later more about it anyway, but if you have one, I'll be thankful).

Comment: Index with randbetween can work, if you give correct bounds for randbetween. The second argument of index is row number *relative* to the range you gave as the first argument. I gave an example of how your command `=index(Spain!A$2:A$19, randbetween(2,19))` can throw an error: it's when the random number happens to be 19.

Comment: Mm, yeah, the _relative_ was (and still is) confusing me, I made a test as the following: =index(England!A$2:A$21, randbetween(1:19)) and it works perfectly, randomizing between from the first (AFC Bournemouth) to the last one (West Ham), I thought it would show the name of the league instead (since it's on A1) and ignore West Ham, because it is out of the range between 1 and 19, but I think that's where  relative plays its part. Thank you for your help and patience teaching me this. :)